# Databases are found in phpmyadmin but contains no tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My old 2003 server became unstable, so I copied the database folder to an external disk in an zip file just before it died and burnt the hard-disc to in the process.

So I am stuck with at hardcopy of my server folder it was setup around ten years ago so it was made in an old version of MySQL and administrated with a just as old version of phpmyadmin.

But no matter which version of phpmyadmin I try I end op with same error it cant find the tables or more correct open them and when I click on a table i get a #1146 error.

Is there anyway around that problem

I am now running on a 2016 server with the latest mysql, php and phpmyadmin and i tried for three months to find a solution, but with no luck sp far.

Is the databases to old to run with the newer versions?

Comment: Is it an sql file?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is just a tool to access the MySQL server. It's not a database. If you're trying to rescue a 2003-era server snapshot you need a 2003 era server like 4.0 or 4.1. Since those are completely obsolete by now you may need to dig up the source and compile it.

Comment: A MySQL `1146` error means the table you're trying to work with doesn't exist. Your `.sql` file may be data-only and lack the table structure as a result, in which case you'd have to reverse-engineer the table structure from the file's contents.

Comment: It is the original database files not an sql file, and it is not a server snapshot, its a clean install from scratch.